# Delete a row in a table after an hour it is inserter using sql query

Tags: sql, sqlite

Am having table which contain a column called datetime which contain date and time as

```
"2013-12-26 09:40:41".
```

I want to delete the row which is an hour old.
Please suggest some queries for it.

This is what I tried.

```
delete from detail1 WHERE datetime(strftime('%s','now') - strftime('%s',datetime) > 3600)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
DELETE FROM detail1 WHERE date < DATETIME('NOW', '-1 hours');
```