# Deleting a row in SQLite after a certain amount of time

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I have a table with one row. I would like to delete this row after one hour. Within this row, I store the timestamp with the specified format as 'COULMN_DATE'. I got the query that should work from here:

[Delete a row in a table after an hour it is inserter using sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785381/delete-a-row-in-a-table-after-an-hour-it-is-inserter-using-sql-query)

And I call it like this in my `onCreate()` function within my databaseHandler class, and I made sure I also updated my database version beforehand. I replaced hour to minutes for checking purposes:

```
 db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS +" 
              WHERE "+ COLUMN_DATE +" < DATETIME('NOW', '-1 minutes');");
```

But after inserting a timestamp, waiting a couple of minutes, and then restarting the application to check whether the data was deleted, it was still there. Is it because I am calling it in the wrong place? If so, where should this query be done?

Comment: `onCreate` is called only when the database does not yet exist. At what point in your app should the row be deleted?

Comment: @CL. Oh I see. On start-up ideally. Or whenever an hour passes. I am unfamiliar with how this is usually done, in the background somehow? As long as an hour has passed, and it's gone by the time the user opens up the program again.

Comment: Why doing anything in the background? Who cares if the row is not yet deleted, when it would not actually be shown until the app is opened again?

Comment: @CL. Yes I suppose. I'm just not so sure how this is commonly done so I was just taking a stab at things.