# How to correctly use times in SQLITE?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table which runs a `DELETE` query every few seconds. With that query I want to delete all entries that are older than 30 seconds.

At the moment I have a value for the creation time in my table `creationdate integer` which contains the date of creation in milliseconds since 1 January 1970.

In my `DELETE` query that I run every 30 seconds I compare it against the current time:

```
delete from table where creationdate < strftime('%s', 'now', '-30.0 seconds')
```

I referred to [this](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) article for the `strftime` formatting.

*This query doesn't delete the entries, that's my problem. It works without the `where` statement so I guess that the function is the problem.*

What am I missing out or is there even a better way to solve this problem?

edit: It doesn't work without the `-30.0 seconds` modifier either, so I think that I misunderstood how `strftime` works. Referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785381/delete-a-row-in-a-table-after-an-hour-it-is-inserter-using-sql-query) question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. I overlooked the fact that in SQLite `strftime('%s')` returns in `SECONDS` and not in `MILLISECONDS`.